# Converting UTF-8 to UTF-16BE

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

I'm wrestling with the following problem. 
I am working with V.S.10 and using the .NET framework 2.0. Coding in C#.

I'm making a simple editor which hands over its text to a **webservice**. I know that .NET uses UTF-16 (I believe the default is LE? And I want Big Endian). I want to make it able to work in any editor and therefore attatch a BOM. The problem is that going through httml it gets changed I believe to UTF-8? Or at least that is what it seems from the following error:

```
Client found response content type of 'text/html; 
charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'. 
The request failed with an empty response.
```

EDIT: the documentation warns that the encoding of all the properties are UTF-8 withOUT a BOM marker. editorTextString is one of the properties. BUT the file content to upload must be in UTF-16BE WITH a BOM. I've checked to see if .net automatically translates the encoding and it does not. Or at least the chinese letters become ?'s. So I need to re-encode or convert better said, the text to UTF-16BE WITH BOM instead of the UTF-8 without BOM that it is in now.

I've looked through a ton of examples and can't see what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone offer advice or correct the code? (Yes I've also read Jon's really cool article about unicode :)) The theory is clear, the actual practice is lacking.

```
        // Convert to UTF-16 Big Endian

        Encoding leUnicode = Encoding.Unicode; 
        Encoding beUnicode = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;

        byte[] editorTextBytesLE = leUnicode.GetBytes(editorTextString);
        Console.WriteLine("Little Endian - Encoded bytes:");
        foreach (Byte b in editorTextBytesLE)
        {
             Console.Write("[{0}]", b);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        byte[] editorTextBytesBE = Encoding.Convert(leUnicode, beUnicode, editorTextBytesLE);
        Console.WriteLine("BIG ENDIAN - Encoded bytes:");
        foreach (Byte b in editorTextBytesBE)
        {
             Console.Write("[{0}]", b);
         }
             Console.WriteLine();

        String decodedString = UnicodeEncoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(editorTextBytesBE);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Decoded bytes:");
        Console.WriteLine(decodedString);

        // inserting UTF-16BE BOM marker, which eases recognition for any editor
        byte[] editorTextBytesToSend = { 0xfe, 0xff };
        editorTextBytesToSend.CopyTo(editorTextBytesBE, 2);


        File.WriteAllText(fileName, decodedString);

        Console.WriteLine("Uploading {0} to {1} ...", fileName, myURL);
        // Upload the file to the URL
        editorTextBytesBE =  myWebClient.UploadFile(myURL, "PUT", fileName);
```

I haven't been able to find anything to switch to big endian, but I've seen some examples (which I couldn't get working alas) to switch TO UTF-8. Would much appreciate any help, examples, or links to get the code to UTF-16BE.

Comment: How exactly (WSDL) is the WebService method defined? It is uncommon to need any of these conversions at all.

Comment: In the WSDL it's defined like this:                                `code` <element name="CreateNote"><complexType><sequence><element    name="Ticket" type="xsd:string"/><element name="Lock" type="xsd:boolean"/><element name="Objects" type="tns:ArrayOfObject"/><element name="Messages" type="tns:ArrayOfMessage" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/><element name="AutoNaming" nillable="true" type="xsd:boolean"/></sequence></complexType></element>

Comment: I can see little connection between uploading an `editorTextString` and the `CreateNote` from WSDL.

Comment: No true. This is the definition of the webservice. editorTextString is one of the properties in the Object Array. That's why I'm stuck. the documentation does warn that the encoding of all the properties are UTF-8 withOUT a BOM marker. editorTextString is one of the properties. BUT  the file content to upload must be in UTF-16BE WITH a BOM. I've checked to see if .net automatically translates the encoding and it does not. Or at least the chinese letters become ?'s. So I need to re-encode or convert better said, the text to UTF-16BE WITH BOM instead of the UTF-8 without BOM that it is in now.

Comment: I'm lost. Why use WebClient at all with a (SOAP) WebService? Have you tried creating a proxy class?

Comment: Is it wrong to do? I do have a SOAP WebService. I saw the WebClient used in a similar example and in the code it seemed to go well. I want to upload the file via http Put. Do you have a better example? That would be great!

Comment: Create a Client and use "Add Web Reference" (Add Service Reference). Plug in the URL of your service and note the namespace.

Comment: I've done that but.. is the problem not in the encoding? Because of the error.

Comment: The error talks about xml/html. I think UTF8 is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a file with BOM in either of UTF-X encoding simply create TextWriter with correct encoding:

```
using(var writer = 
    new StreamWriter(fileName, new Encoding.UnicodeEncoding(true,true,true))
{
   writer.Write(editorTextString);
}
```

Use [UnicodeEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98ffd8aa%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) constructor that give BOM.

Side note: there is a good chance that your problem is not related to use of this rare encoding, but it should fix what your code tries to do now.

Comment: Hmm Is that really how it's supposed to be used? I get errors with that - with the unicode error, Unicode works fine and there are other things I can do such as UTF7, or 8:  Error 1 'System.IO.StreamWriter' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' and Error 2 'System.Text.Encoding' does not contain a definition for 'UnicodeEncoding'

Comment: @SuusvdVen, should be better now.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

The following code does not look like it is *inserting* anything. Instead it overwrites 2 bytes at positions 2 and 3 with your BOM. It skips the first 2.

```
 // inserting UTF-16BE BOM marker, which eases recognition for any editor
    byte[] editorTextBytesToSend = { 0xfe, 0xff };
    editorTextBytesToSend.CopyTo(editorTextBytesBE, 2);
```

Comment: Yes actually I'm having some problems finding a good example of inserting a BOM, plenty examples of deleting it :P  This was more a guess and try, but do you have an idea (or link) to where I could find a good example?

Comment: I think you should first find out if any of this is necessary at all.

Comment: Unfortunately it does seem to be. As I do wish the editor to be able to convert any language and it currently does not without conversion. I first tested if the text went through the http alright and it did not. The encoding of the properties is UTF-8 without BOM. the webservice needs UTF16-BE With BOM.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work with the following code:

byte[] BOMTextBytesToSend = {0xfe, 0xff };

byte[] editorTextBytesToSend = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(editorTextString);

BOMTextBytesToSend.CopyTo(editorTextBytesToSend, 0);